# JS show/hide default behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change the default behavior so that ONLY the contents of the div with the id of films is initially shown?

JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function () {
    var targetDiv = $(location.hash);
    if (!targetDiv.is(':visible')) {
        $('.page').slideUp();
        targetDiv.slideDown();
    } else {
        $('.page').slideUp();
    }
}, false);
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s9cxjrmf/

I tried adding `display: none` to the page `div` initially but that doesn't solve my problem at all since it hides everything at start instead of displaying everything. All I need is to keep its functionality while displaying the first div's content only when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line

```
$('#films').show();
```

in your script to resolve your issue..

Answer (score 1):

When you are using jQuery, use jQuery's event handling style:

```js
$(window).on("hashchange", function () {
    var targetDiv = $(location.hash);
    if (!targetDiv.is(':visible')) {
        $('.page').slideUp();
        targetDiv.slideDown();
    } else {
        $('.page').slideUp();
    }
}).trigger('hashchange');
```

```css
.page {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#films" class="navLink">Films</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#tv_films" class="navLink">TV Films</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#tv_shows" class="navLink">TV Shows</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#special_events" class="navLink">Special Events</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="films" class="page">
  <img src="https://www.organicfacts.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Banana21.jpg">
</div>
<div id="tv_films" class="page">
  <img src="http://a.dilcdn.com/bl/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2012/12/no-bundle-deal.jpg">
</div>
<div id="tv_shows" class="page">
  <img src="http://www.med-health.net/images/10416152/image001.jpg">
</div>
<div id="special_events" class="page">
  <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41fqB7D6eNL._SX466_.jpg">
</div>
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s9cxjrmf/2/**

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery event handlers and can trigger the event on load so that the default view is set

```
$(window).on("hashchange", function () {
    var targetDiv = $(location.hash).stop(true, true);
    if (!targetDiv.is(':visible')) {
        $('.page').not(targetDiv).slideUp();
        targetDiv.slideDown();
    } else {
        $(window).slideUp();
    }
});
if (location.hash) {
    $(window).trigger('hashchange');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the hash value to the `films` on page load. This'll show the content of the `films` on page load.

Add

```
window.location.hash = 'films';
```

to your Javascript.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/s9cxjrmf/4/)

```js
window.location.hash = 'films';
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function() {
  var targetDiv = $(location.hash);
  if (!targetDiv.is(':visible')) {
    $('.page').slideUp();
    targetDiv.slideDown();
  } else {
    $('.page').slideUp();
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.page {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#films" class="navLink">Films</a>

  </li>
  <li><a href="#tv_films" class="navLink">TV Films</a>

  </li>
  <li><a href="#tv_shows" class="navLink">TV Shows</a>

  </li>
  <li><a href="#special_events" class="navLink">Special Events</a>

  </li>
</ul>
<div id="films" class="page">
  <img src="https://www.organicfacts.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Banana21.jpg">
</div>
<div id="tv_films" class="page">
  <img src="http://a.dilcdn.com/bl/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2012/12/no-bundle-deal.jpg">
</div>
<div id="tv_shows" class="page">
  <img src="http://www.med-health.net/images/10416152/image001.jpg">
</div>
<div id="special_events" class="page">
  <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41fqB7D6eNL._SX466_.jpg">
</div>
```

**EDIT**

You can also use CSS to show the section on page load.

```
#films {
    display: block
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/s9cxjrmf/5/)

Comment: While this solution works, when I open the website it goes to the films section. I only want the films section to be displayed, not to go to it when the page opens. :)

Comment: @MateiPanchios Check the `EDIT` section at the bottom of the answer. Added CSS-only solution