# Show/hide and slider conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

A few days ago I asked a question regarding a show/hide div script that I had problems with.

[JS show/hide default behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246297/js-show-hide-default-behavior)

Tested all the solutions and nothing seemed to work on my website (they all work in fiddles or different areas of the website than the one I need it in). The problem is that inside the show/hide divs I have a slider. There are 4 tabs, each showing a different slider. My best guess is that the problem appears because both the slider and the show/hide use the same display:none, altering the slider's content.

Here's the JS that I currently have for the show/hide:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function () {
    var targetDiv = $(location.hash);
    if (!targetDiv.is(':visible')) {
        $('.page1').slideUp();
        targetDiv.slideDown();
    } else {
        $('.page1').slideUp();
    }
}, false);
```

The slider I use is called Flickity and it's link is; https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flickity/1.1.0/flickity.pkgd.js

The link of the live website is:
http://theworkshop.ro/astra3/

Here's the fiddle of the show/hide: http://jsfiddle.net/s9cxjrmf/ (currently the .page css is commented to show all 4 show sliders, if I add display none as it is in the fiddle it doesn't work anymore, it only shows the arrows of the slider, not it's content)

The problem is in the Work section of the website.

I'm struggling for a few days, any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please describe in details what is not working? My understanding is that the jsfiddle is showing a correct result. Isnt'it ?

Comment: Yes, except for the fact the first div is not showing (easily fixed with a     `$('#films').show();`) it's working as intended. Try opening the website and go to the Work section. You'll see 4 sliders, one after the other. It should only display one slider. If I add `display:none;` it doesn't show any slider anymore, just slider navigation, not it's content.

Comment: I am now checking within that page and it seams that for some strange reason the div contained in the"page" div is remaining hidden (the one with this class "gallery js-flickity flickity-enabled is-draggable"): maybe the problem is that that slider is not able to handle the inner div correctly when the outer "page" div is hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code it will hide all the div inside the #work_box and again displays the first one that way the script running for hiding and showing the div will work hope this will help you.

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "#work_box div" ).each(function() {
           $( this ).css( "display", "none" );
        });

        $( "#work_box div" ).first().css( "display", "block" );

        $('#work_box div').first().find(':hidden').each(function(){
           $(this).show();
        });
    });
```

This is working for the first div you need to repeat this.

```
$('#work_box div').first().find(':hidden').each(function(){
    $(this).show();
});
```

for other div when user click on the other links like films,tv_shows etc.

Comment: Added this to the script, now it won't display anything in the container, it displays just the empty box and clicking on the tab links just tries to find the links #films, #tv_films, etc. :(

Comment: just repeat the code mention above for your other link click events you problem will be resolve :)

Comment: Indeed that solved my problem regarding the first div but i don't understand what you mean by repeating the second part for the others. Can you elaborate pls? I'm a total noob when it comes to JS. :)

Comment: when you click on other links films or etc it shows blank div all the content goes blank due to display:none css but, if you repeat the last line from the code it will start displaying properly. I have written this code for first div only, I am not able to test for other hidden div because i dont have the code, if its working for you then its fine :) please accept if you like

Comment: Sure, it works for the first but I my four divs are: #films, #tv_films, #tv_shows and #special_events. I don't understand how I can target them since this script seems to only target the #work_box div, right? Sorry for being a pain in the arse but I try to understand how to fix it all the way.

Comment: register click event for other for divs using this $(#films).on('click',function(){ //call the above line }); it will work in this way

Comment: so.. `$(#tv_films).on('click',function(){ $('#work_box div').first().find(':hidden').each(function(){
    $(this).show();
}); })` like this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88355/discussion-between-matei-panchios-and-ashish-ranade).