# JQuery second()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "#work_box div" ).each(function() {
           $( this ).css( "display", "none" );
        });

        $( "#work_box div" ).first().css( "display", "block" );

        $('#work_box div').first().find(':hidden').each(function(){
           $(this).show();
        });
    });
```

And I need to make it work for 4 divs. This script is meant for the first one, how can I target the others? It's linked to the accepted answer in the [Show/hide and slider conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305987/show-hide-and-slider-conflict/32306366#32306366) question. I realise it's a noob question but that's my level in JS. :)

Tried looking on google for some solutions but all I can find is nth-child()...

Comment: For selecting the second element in the set you can use the `eq` method. `$('#work_box div').eq(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`.eq(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to work with a jquery object collection as an array,

```
   var divs = $("#work_box div").hide();
   divs.eq(0).show().find(':hidden').show(); //for 1st div
   divs.eq(1).show().find(':hidden').show(); //for 2nd div
```

But I am swear to god, I don't know what you are trying to achieve with this.

Comment: Uhmm... what if I told you I'm not really sure either? :D I'm just trying to implement the answer to the linked question.